# question about the chrome webdriver options

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to use the headless and download setting.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')

chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
"download.default_directory":{fold_name},
"download.prompt_for_download": False,
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

This is my setting but when I try to set the headless option, download option doesn't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You may want to check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743818/question-about-the-chrome-webdriver-options  (The first answer says "--headless=new" would be your solution)

Answer (score 1):

Current chrome has 2 headless modes:

1. old = which does not allow downlaods and it is the default one when used like syntax in the question.
2. new = this will be the default in the newer builds, works exactly like headful chrome but without head! it can be accessed using "--headless=new" (like mate's answer)

ref:
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/

Answer (score 0):

The way to add arguments to chrome options is

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
```

for selenium newer then 4.8.0.

For older versions, use

```
chrome_options.headless = True
```

Comment: my selenium is old version so i use chrome_options.headless =True
but same problem do again...download option doesn`t work...